# Convert from GeoTiff to SVG

Tags: convert, geotiff-tiff, file-formats, svg, data

I have a customer who can only export structured map data as a GeoTiff file. My job is to convert this file into proper SVG.

How can this be done?

I have googled about gdal, [but obsiously it is not supported](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_formats.html); see also [format list](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_formats.html)

Comment: 'converting' is probably a little misleading. It would be also enough if only the spacial information could be turned into an SVG from a world map source.

Comment: Found this tool: http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-svg

It accepts geotiff, but the SVG output seems rather poor, i.e. incomplete.

Comment: Did you try Inkscape (free) or if you have it Illustrator?

Comment: Could you provide more information about your input GeoTIFF data and what the output should look like? It needs be mentioned that GeoTIFF is a raster format whereas SVG is a vector format so conversion is non-trivial.

Comment: Apart from GDAL what software do you have available? Surely it would be better to go back to your mapping software and change the export to SVG (ArcGis will export SVG).

Answer (score 1):

I image you want to capture vector data from your raster image. You can do it with GDAL however, I like PKTOOLS
http://pktools.nongnu.org/html/pkpolygonize.html
THEN convert the Shape file to SVG with Arc MAP or sho to AI or EPS then to SVG.